# How to merge variables into an array while retaining the variable name as key

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
$countries = array( 
 "af" => "Afghanistan",
 "ax" => "Åland Islands",
 "al" => "Albania",
 "dz" => "Algeria"
);
```

and some variables:

```
$as = "American Samoa";
$ad = "Andorra";
```

How do I combine the variables into the array while keeping the variable name as the key in the array?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`compact`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) to create an array out of your variables and then simply [add the two arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) together:

```
$countries += compact('as', 'ad');
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/fdI6S)**.

Comment: That's great! I know compact but never thought of using it this way. Thanks!

Comment: I did not know it was THAT simple. It is always great to learn something new.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(array('as','ad') as $name){
  $countries[$name] = $$name;
}
```